# Add a URL path prefix to artifactory installation (Docker)

Tags: docker, redirect, artifactory, traefik

I'm running *Artifactory CPP CE 7.7.3* and  *Traefik v2.2* using `docker-compose`. The service is only available over `http://localhost/ui/`. Now, what I need is an option which allows to add a URL path-prefix (e. g. `http://localhost/artifactroy/ui`).

#### My Setup

- I used the described setup process from the [Artifactory Docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerComposeInstallation) suggest it.
- My [docker.compose.yaml](https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Artifactory-Cpp-CE/view) is the official extracted from the *jfrog-artifactory-cpp-ce-7.7.3-compose.tar.gz*: `./templates/docker-compose.yaml`.
- I'm using a reverse proxy (traefik). For this, I've added the necessary traefik configuration lines to the docker-compose-file. Here is a small extract what I've added:

  ```yaml
  [...]
  labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.artifactory.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/ui`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.artifactory.middlewares=artifactory-stripprefix"
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.artifactory-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/"
    - "traefik.http.services.artifactory.loadbalancer.server.port=8082"
  ```

**With this I managed to access artifactory over `http://localhost/ui/`.**

---

#### Problem:

I have multiple small services running on my server, each of this service is accusable via `http://localhost/<service-name>`. This is very convenient and want to make clear that this URL is related to this service on my production server.
Because of this, I want to have an URL like *`http://localhost/artifactroy/ui/...`* instead of *`http://localhost/ui/...`*

I struggled getting artifactory setup in that way. I already managed to get a redirection from typing e. g. `http://localhost/artifactroy/` to `http://localhost/ui/` but this is not what I want on my production server.

#### What I did

- Went through the documentation in hope of finding an option which I just can passt to artifactroy to add a prefix (**Not** successful).
- Tried configure traefik two full days, to alter headers to get the repose point to `http://localhost/artifactroy/ui/...` (Only partially successful, redirection didn’t work afterwards)
- Tried finding the configuration which is responsible for configure artifactory in `$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc` (**Not** successful)

**Is this even possible?** Help is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This example (even though not traefic example) gives you a direction to implement it. There are certain routes already used within the product. You need to add a context over and above it to ensure all comes via the new context path.

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-remove-artifactory-from-the-context-url-in-artifactory-7/